# Ler um caractere especial tipo char utilizando locale não funciona. Como corrigir?

Tags: c, utf-8, locale

Eu vou dar um exemplo bem simples pra explicar a minha dúvida:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    char a;

    printf("Insira um caractere especial,\nExemplos: ç, á, é, ê, ã, à...\n>>");
    scanf("%c", &a);

    printf("Você digitou '%c'", a);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Ele não considera o locale ao ler o caractere do usuário, gostaria de aprender a corrigir isso!
Já me falaram que é necessário mudar a codificação de caractere do DEV C++ para UTF-8, essa informação procede? Porque eu não achei como se faz isso...